# Multiple rewrite rule does not works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my current `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv CI_ENV development
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now this code allow me to access to any url directory and it calls the index.php file. Example:

```
http://example.com/             => Call index.php file
http://example.com/index.php    => Call index.php file
http://example.com/index/       => Call index.php file
http://example.com/api/         => Call index.php file
http://example.com/api/add      => Call index.php file
http://example.com/api/delete   => Call index.php file
http://example.com/post/        => Call index.php file
http://example.com/post/hello   => Call index.php file
```

Now I want to do is to have a file name `api.php` and this file needs to be activated when the URL is pointing to the `api` folder. Example:

```
http://example.com/             => Call index.php file
http://example.com/index.php    => Call index.php file
http://example.com/index/       => Call index.php file
http://example.com/api/         => Call api.php file
http://example.com/api/add      => Call api.php file
http://example.com/api/delete   => Call api.php file
http://example.com/post/        => Call index.php file
http://example.com/post/hello   => Call index.php file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv CI_ENV development
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This produce an error 500 with this message: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context

Comment: Without it I got a 404

Comment: with `api.php` ? Is it in the `api/` directory ?

Comment: Looks like this was working since the first moment but for some reason my framework acted on a unexpected way...